# Setting horizontal vs. vertical orientation for Highlights component

Tags: lightning-app-builder, highlights-panel

According to https://www.salesforce.com/content/dam/web/en_us/www/documents/platform/salesforce-only-in-lightning-features.pdf:

> Use new Lightning App Builder attributes to display the highlights panel in less
>   space, show fewer buttons, and **change the orientation from horizontal to vertical**.

However, I see no such option. The problem is when I place the Highlights panel in a region on a template which I have myself defined, even one that extends across the entire width of the page, it still displays it in vertical mode.

How can I force the Highlights panel to display in horizontal mode in a region I've defined in my own template, whether or not it crosses the entire page? Are there any know reasons why a region in a  user-defined template would cause a Highlights panel (also the Path component, by the way) to display in vertical rather than horizontal mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What are the defaultWidth and width properties on the region in your template? The reported template region width is used to drive how the component renders.

Check out the docs at https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_config_for_app_builder_template_component.htm

Comment: Yes, I figured that out, thanks for the tip.